# Edit was rejected to correct the wrong tag

Tags: support, tags, rejected-edits

The below edit was reject. The OP tagged the post as Java but its not java, its Javascript. The reject states:

> This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the
>   revision history to see what should have been changed.

The edit was to correct the tag, not the post. Thats not a Java question, it Javascript. Am I crazy?

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7940432

Comment: Your suggestion was approved by one user.But someone else modified the question and your suggestion was rejected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% familiar with how conflicting edits are always handled and the exact scenario that could cause this, but it looks like another user was trying to add the [web-inf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-inf) tag, which conflict with your tag edit, and his edit took place.

[image]

---

[image]

The time your edit was rejected (and the user who rejected it) correspond with another edit.

In any case, I've edited the question to appropriate have the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag.